# How To Insert Multiple Row into Database PHP MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mysqli

i need help for my Invoice input

I need some help for inserting multipe rows with different values to database using php. i already have button to insert new row

here is my insert query :

```
  $insert     = "INSERT INTO subtrans (idproduk,namaproduk,harga,qty,sub) 
  VALUES";
      for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        $insert .= "('{$idproduk[$i]}','{$namaproduk[$i]}','{$harga[$i]}','{$qty[$i]}','{$sub[$i]}')";
        $insert .= ",";
      }
    $insert = rtrim($insert,",");
    $sql = $con->query($insert);
```

heres my HTML code :

```
<tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-type="idproduk" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control form-control-sm autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" data-type="namaproduk" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control form-control-sm autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control form-control-sm changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control form-control-sm changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control form-control-sm totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
```

And here is my js code :

```
//adds extra table rows
var i=$('table tr').length;
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
 html = '<tr>';
 html += '<td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="idproduk" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_'+i+'" class="form-control form-control-sm autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" data-type="namaproduk" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_'+i+'" class="form-control form-control-sm autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off"></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" name="price[]" id="price_'+i+'" class="form-control form-control-sm changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;"onpaste="return false;"></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+i+'" class="form-control form-control-sm changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;"  onpaste="return false;"></td>';
 html += '<td><input type="text" name="total[]" id="total_'+i+'" class="form-control form-control-sm totalLinePrice" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;"  onpaste="return false;"></td>';
 html += '</tr>';
 $('table').append(html);
 i++;
 });
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: i was insert data but there's no insert multiple just single data, so the second data doesn't inputed

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: multiple insert is not working , only single data inputed to database . i didn't get any error massage

Comment: please post the output of `var_dump($insert);` to see the generated query

Comment: What is the `$count` ?

Comment: The obligatory comment is required perhaps  "your sql is at risk of sql injection"

Comment: string(112) "INSERT INTO subtrans (idproduk,namaproduk,harga,qty,sub) VALUES('MRW0001','Sunscreen Cream','55000','1','55000')"

Comment: only first row to be inserted

Comment: $count to count the row

Comment: Where are you getting these variables? `$idproduk,$namaproduk,$harga,$qty, $sub`? They do not directly relate to the fields so there must be other code which you have omitted!

Comment: $idkons     = $_POST['idkons'];
        $namakons   = $_POST['namakons'];
        $tlpcons    = $_POST['tlpkons'];
        $addcons    = $_POST['addkons'];
        $idproduk   = $_POST['itemNo'];
        $namaproduk = $_POST['itemName'];
        $harga      = $_POST['price'];
        $qty        = $_POST['quantity'];
        $sub        = $_POST['total'];

Comment: For this type of question, might I suggest writing a unit test that other users can simply copy and paste into their ide and run. That would probably also help you narrow down where your problem is occurring. The test should have test input data, and expected results. Since you have server side and client side code, you could create two separate unit tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the record I do not believe this to be the best way to approach this particular problem - the better way would be to use a `prepared statement` which is prepared once and then executed multiple times in the loop using different values each time. However, the following generates viable sql ( did in testing anyway )

```
$insert = "insert into `subtrans` ( `idproduk`, `namaproduk`, `harga`, `qty`, `sub` ) values ";
$params = array();

foreach( $_POST['itemName'] as $i => $value ){
    $params[]="'". implode( "','", 
        array( 
                $_POST['itemNo'][ $i ],
                $_POST['itemName'][ $i ],
                $_POST['price'][ $i ],
                $_POST['quantity'][ $i ],
                $_POST['total'][ $i ]
            )
        ) ."'";
}
$sql = sprintf("%s ( %s )", $insert, implode( '),(', $params ) );

echo $sql;
$result = $con->query( $sql );
```

The better method to use would be, like I mentioned, a `prepared statement` executed multiple times.

```
$sql='insert into `subtrans` ( `idproduk`, `namaproduk`, `harga`, `qty`, `sub` ) values (?,?,?,?,?)';
$stmt=$con->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bind_param('ssddd',$id,$name,$price,$qty,$total);

    foreach( $_POST['itemName'] as $i => $value ){
        $id=$_POST['itemNo'][ $i ];
        $name=$_POST['itemName'][ $i ];
        $price=$_POST['price'][ $i ];
        $qty=$_POST['quantity'][ $i ];
        $total=$_POST['total'][ $i ];

        $stmt->execute()
    }
}
```